# XSD validation of attribute values against other element attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have an XML file:

```
<tasks>
    <task name="task-12">
        <step>Open folder</step>
        <step nextTask="task-14">Delete contents.</step>
    </task>
    <task name="task-13">
        <step nextTask="task-16">Create new folder folder</step>
    </task>
    <task name="task-14">
        <step>Move files into folder.</step>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

How would I go about specifying in an XSD that the `step/@nextTask` value is only valid if it matches a value of a `task/@name`.

i.e. In the above example, the step of **task-13** would be considered invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way: declare the task `name` attribute to be of type `xsd:ID` and the step `nextTask` attribute to be of type `xsd:IDREF`.